# SSE returned data is x50 large than the file size

Tags: node.js, hapi, eventsource

We have a hapijs server running which returns an SSE stream containing rows returned from a readable SQL Server (NOT MySQL) stored procedure.

We observed 50,000 rows returned in chunks of 1000 events. Both Chrome and Firefox indicated that the size of the data returned in the request was just under 250mbs. We copied the data returned (JSON) and placed it into a .txt file and noticed that the data was only 20mb.

The content encoding is set to identity. We implemented SUSIE and are using that to return the event source.

```
  let result = await server.methods.services.worklist.getData(request.query);
  let rowsToProcess = [];
  let chunkSizeSmall = 50;    // @todo move this to the config
  let chunkSizeLarge = 1000;  // @todo move this to the config
  let chunkSize = chunkSizeSmall;

  result.on('recordset', columns => {
    h.event({ event: 'columns', data: columns })
  });

  result.on('row', row => {
    rowsToProcess.push(row);
    if (rowsToProcess.length >= chunkSize) {  
      chunkSize = chunkSizeLarge;                       
      result.pause();
      processRows();
    }
  });

  result.on('done', () => {
    processRows();
    h.event(null)
  });

  function processRows() {
    // process rows
    h.event({ event: 'data', data: rowsToProcess })
    rowsToProcess = [];
    result.resume();
  }
  return h.event({});
```

We are expecting the output to be the same or somewhat near the same size as the filesize of the JSON.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue in my repo. The eventStream size is 50x the size of the data transferred.